# Django Ignoring Asynch Tests Completely (Django Channels)

Tags: python, django, testing, django-channels

I'm working on a web server running Python3.6, Django 2.0 and Channels 2.0.2. I'd like to build some tests to make sure my websocket consumers are behaving themselves, unfortunately, whenever I run the tests they are all ignored completely.

I've been following the [official Channels documentation on testing](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/testing.html), and I copied the code Channels [uses to test its generic consumers](https://github.com/django/channels/blob/master/tests/test_generic_websocket.py) as is but whenever I run the tests, the test runner simply reports that it ran no tests:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I get no errors or other warnings. I've double checked that I've installed `pytest-asyncio` and `pytest-django`, and I'm 100% sure the file itself is being loaded by placing a print statement at the top. All my other tests run normally. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have this same issue, throwing print statements before the file assures me that the file is being loaded and simply putting `assert False` in the function body does nothing as the test is simply never run.

Comment: Try asking this on their [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/django-developers), or maybe create an issue on Github.

Comment: You need to run the tests with `pytest`, as the tests are incompatible with the standard `unittest` library (functions instead of test classes, this is why `unittest` does not discover any tests). This is also what `channels` do in their `.travis.yml`.

Comment: If you want to try running the `channels` tests, install Django and `channels` with test extras: `pip install Django channels[tests]` and run `pytest` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default Django test runner is not implemented to work with asyncio and will not properly auto-discover test functions decorated with `@pytest.mark.asyncio`.

[The FAQ does a decent job of outlining the reasons tests wont be found](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#faq-tests-not-being-picked-up) but here's what I did in order to fix this issue on my end.

Install the libraries `pytest`, `pytest-django`, and `pytest-asyncio`.

```
pipenv install pytest pytest-django pytest-asyncio
```

Create a file `pytest.ini` at the root of your project containing the following and swap `projectname.settings` for the proper name of your projects settings file.

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = projectname.settings
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
```

I was then able to run the tests using `pytest` as described in https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/testing.html

If this still doesn't work, give this a look-through: https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#faq-tests-not-being-picked-up